# Line integral of a Vector Field around a Closed path

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This is just a little question.

Suppose you want to evaluate an integral around a closed path formed by a curve $C(t) $(only one curve), I suspect that the result would be $0$, because you will do an integral from the point $P$ to the same point.

so for example if $P=C(a)$, then your integral is $$\int_CF=\int_a ^a F(C(t))\cdot C'(t)\,dt = 0$$

Is that true?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It depends on whether vector field is conservative or not.

Comment: Your earlier question, I think yesterday, was a closed curve formed by a parabola and line $x = 1$ but the line integral was not zero.

Comment: I'm not talking about a path formed by more than one curve @MathLover

Comment: It does not matter. It was piecewise smooth, simple closed curve and vector field was defined over the region. You can take a circle instead. If the vector field is not conservative in the domain, then it is not necessary that the line integral over a closed curve would be zero.

Comment: If this helps - https://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_determine#:~:text=If%20the%20vector%20field%20is%20defined%20inside%20every%20closed%20curve,the%20vector%20field%20is%20conservative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You will do an integral from the point $P$ to the same point.

This is true in *certain* situations. The [Fundamental Theorem For Line Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem) says that if your vector function $\mathbf F$ is the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of a [scalar function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field) $f$, then you can replace these sorts of line integrals (like $\int_C \mathbf F(\mathbf C(t))\cdot \mathbf C'(t)\,\mathrm dt$) with a difference in the values of $f$ at the endpoints. In a situation like that, you are correct that the integral over a closed loop $C$ must be zero since the two endpoints would be the same. (It doesn't matter whether if the loop $C$ is given by single formula for $\mathbf{C}(t)$ or if there is a piecewise definition.)

---

However, if $\mathbf F$ is **not** the gradient of a scalar function, then we don't have an analog of that theorem, and the integrals around closed loops are often nonzero. The line integral of $\mathbf F$ measures how much $\mathbf F$ goes along with the direction of the curve $C$; see [Lucas Vieira's animation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Line_integral_of_vector_field.gif) featured in [the line integral of a vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field) section of the English Wikipedia article for "Line Integral", for one illustration. So the integral around a loop can be nonzero as long as the direction of $\mathbf F$ is aligned with the loop.

A famous example would be $\mathbf F(x,y)=\left\langle\dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right\rangle$ (inspired by the [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) $\left\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\right\rangle$). [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20vector%20field&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22VectorPlot%22%2C%20%22vectorplotupperrange2%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22VectorPlot%22%2C%20%22vectorplotupperrange1%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22VectorPlot%22%2C%20%22vectorfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B-y%2FSqrt%5Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%5D%2Cx%2FSqrt%5Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%5D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22VectorPlot%22%2C%20%22vectorplotvariable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22VectorPlot%22%2C%20%22vectorplotlowerrange1%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22VectorPlot%22%2C%20%22vectorplotvariable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22VectorPlot%22%2C%20%22vectorplotlowerrange2%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22) plots this vector field like this:
[image: counterclockwise arrows]

Since the vectors of $\mathbf F$ are all going counterclockwise around the origin, we should expect the line integral of $\mathbf F$ around a counterclockwise loop around the origin to be positive. Indeed, if we integrate over the counterclockwise loop $C$ of radius $r$ parametrized by $\mathbf C(t)=\left\langle r\cos t,r\sin t\right\rangle$ for $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, then \begin{align*}&\phantom{=}\oint_C\mathbf F\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf C\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf F(\mathbf C(t))\cdot\mathbf C'(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf F(r\cos t,r\sin t)\cdot\left\langle -r\sin t,r\cos t\right\rangle\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left\langle \dfrac{-r\sin t}{\sqrt{r^2\cos^2t+r^2\sin^2t}},\dfrac{r\cos t}{\sqrt{r^2\cos^2t+r^2\sin^2t}}\right\rangle\cdot\left\langle -r\sin t,r\cos t\right\rangle\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left\langle -\sin t,\cos t\right\rangle\cdot\left\langle -r\sin t,r\cos t\right\rangle\,\mathrm dt\\&=r\int_0^{2\pi}\left\langle -\sin t,\cos t\right\rangle\cdot\left\langle -\sin t,\cos t\right\rangle\,\mathrm dt\\&=r\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2t+\cos^2t\,\mathrm dt\\&=r\int_0^{2\pi}1\,\mathrm dt\\&=2\pi r>0\end{align*}

Comment: ‘The line integral of   measures how much  goes along with the direction of the curve ’, that’s a good explanation of what the line integral is. @MarkS.